# Why is npm install downloading other useless plugins into my node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, frontend

I just started getting into node.js and terminal. My issue is that, whenever I am doing an npm install of a plugin, i.e lets say 'sudo npm install browser-sync', it downloads a bunch of useless plugins into my node_modules folder. I didn't have this issue before reformating my Mac.

I want it to behave like it used to before, which in this case, download only the browser-sync plugin into my node_modules folder. Right now I've got 223 folders including browser-sync inside my node_modules. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: because you're using npm 3.x

Comment: It isn't downloading "more" plugins, it's just putting them in a different place than before. Now you can clearly see just how many plugins you are actually installing.

Comment: Thanks for the info man. Sorry I didn't read the latest changelog. I thought I was going crazy!

Comment: Yes, it's a new feature.